# How to import object with methods from ES5 javascript using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need to import an ES5 javascript file with a 'class object' named BrowserPrint. The method of emulating a class is complex, something with wrapping inside a function, but with no prototype stuff.

Anyway, in a jQuery project I was able to import and utilize this file in order to print to a label printer. Import was with:

```
<script src='foo.js'></script>
```

Usage was fine with code like:

```
<script>
    BrowserPrint.getDefaultDevice(x, y, z)
```

Now I need to import this same javascript in a React project using WebPack. I tried with 2 methods:

```
import BrowserPrint from 'foo.js'
//var BrowserPrint require('foo.js')

class Zebra{
  constructor(){
    const x = BrowserPrint //object
    const y = BrowserPrint.getDefaultDevice //undefined
```

With either method of importing, in the Chrome debugger, I could see that x became an object, but y was undefined.

I could study the foo.js, which is not that big, and rewrite it in ES6, but it seems complex. For now I was assuming that if foo.js contains a 'class', it should be possible to just import it into ES6.

But how to get access to the class method like .getDefaultDevice() ?

---

Update:

The thing to import is complex, foo.js looks something like:

```
var BrowserPrint = function(){
  var t = {}
  return 
    t.Device = function(t) {
    ...
    },
    t
}();
```

so I changed the name to `_BrowserPrint` and added ES6 classes below, in the same foo.js file, to call the old ES5 style stuff with a nice ES6 class code:

```
export class BrowserPrint {
    constructor() {
        this.dummy = 'abc'
    }
    getDefaultDevice(a, b, c) {
        _BrowserPrint.getDefaultDevice(a, b, c)
    }
    getLocalDevices(a, b, c) {
        _BrowserPrint.getLocalDevices(a, b, c)
    }
}
// for the subclass
export class BrowserPrintDevice {
    constructor(device) {
        //device is a _BrowserPrint object
        this.selected_device = device
    }
    send(a, b, c) {
        this.selected_device.send(a, b, c)
    }
}
```

I tested this is a simple html with script block like:

```
<script src='foo.js'></script>
<script>
  var zebra = new BrowserPrint()
  zebra.getLocalDevices(x, y, z)
```

and the entire system works just fine, I can print labels.

Now I thought it should be much simpler to import the `class` stuff in my JSX.

```
import BrowserPrint from 'foo.js'
import BrowserPrintDevice from 'foo.js'
...
const w = BrowserPrint //undefined
const x = new BrowserPrint() //not a constructor
const y = x.getDefaultDevices //error...
const z = x.getDefaultDevices(x, y, z) //error...
```

It seems that I am doing something very basic very wrong, probably with the `import`.

With the Chrome dev tools debugger I cannot even get into the constructor dummy code.

Comment: Try `import 'foo.js'; window.BrowserPrint.getDefaultDevice(x, y, z);`

Comment: @spirift thanks, but `window.BrowserPrint` is undefined, so this import seems to not import anything !? I looked all over in the Chrome debugger, could not find BrowserPrint. Still, the js starts with `export var BrowserPrint = function () { `

Comment: It was a bit of a shot in the dark. Try `import {BrowserPrint} from 'foo'`

Comment: @spirift Shot in the dark is OK. import {BrowserPrint} did not work, `const x = BrowserPrint` was undefined. I am trying to make a better JS test in order to edit foo.js

Comment: What properties are on the BrowserPrint object when you console it? Also have a look in the prototype chain

Comment: @spirift good points, i will look harder in the chrome dev tools. I have also new test code from the manuf. It might take a while before I have news to report

Comment: @spirift Please have a look at the update in the question, using real ES6 class code. Am I wrong in how I use the `import` ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the new class you have written is exported as a named export. The import statement should be `import { BrowserPrint } from 'foo'`

Comment: @spirift Fresh at the start of a new week, and with your comment, I found it. With `import bla from` we need `export default bla`. To export one or more classes, without the `default` keyword, this becomes `import { class1, class2, ... } from `. Things work much better now

Comment: Had the exact same problem with Vue. My workaround was add foo.js to public directory and then add <script src="js/foo.js"></script> to index.html